# Regex String Matching - Potential Backslash Issue

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am relatively new to Python but jumping right in.  I am trying to find out why my string isn't matching properly.  Basically, I am evaluating a text file to see if a registry key and path is present.  This is for sure not the sexiest code you have ever seen but here is the function that does the regex checking:

```
     def stigeval (content, regex1, regex2):
        # Now set the registry key path and value
        regex = re.compile(regex1, re.IGNORECASE)

        match = re.search(regex, content)
        if match != None:
            findex = match.start()
            regpathpass = True
            regex = re.compile(regex2, re.IGNORECASE)
            match = re.search(regex, content)
            if match != None:
                findex = match.start()
                regkeypass = True
            else:
                regkeypass = False
        else:
            regpathpass = False
            regkeypass = False

        return(regpathpass, regkeypass)
```

Here is what I am passing the function:

```
cregex1 = r'(HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\|HKCU\\|HKCU:\\)\\Software\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Office\\14\.0\\word\\security\\fileblock'
            cregex2 = r'Word97Files\s*=\s*5'

            status = stigeval(content, cregex1, cregex2)
```

And here is what content is:

```
01/14/2020 16:28:20
Temp
 HKCU:\\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\14.0\word\security\fileblock\Word97Files = 5.
```

By my evaluation, the regex should match the key above but it is returning False for some reason.  I am sure this is because I missed something. The crux of my issue is that the match isn't being made.

```
findex = re.search(regex, content).start()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'
```

Comment: You should not use a backslash matching ``\\`` before `|`  in an alternation.

Comment: So looking at the content I posted, how would you recommend that I match for any of the situations?  I can't think of a better way to see if the reg key is HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ OR HKCU\ OR HKCU:\\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flags for compiled patterns should be passed to `re.compile` instead.

Your code is very hard to read and follow, and also way too complex for such a simple task.

Try to avoid unnecessary try blocks by catching the error before-hand:

```
match = re.search(regex, content)
if match != None:
    findex = match.start()
```

Also avoid nesting if statements by handling the simpler else case instead

```
if findex < 0:
    return
regex = ...
```

All of this could have been prevented if only you had printed the error:

```
except Exception as e:
    print(e) # cannot process flags argument with a compiled pattern
```

Comment: I switched the flag to the compiled statement and adjusted my except statements but I am still not getting a match even thought I think the regex is written correctly.  Do you have any other suggestions for how I could troubleshoot this?

Comment: @SureThing edit your question to include the current code, after making the changes i listed in the answer it worked for me.

Comment: Code has been updated.  I wish I could just open a chat room with yall

Comment: I updated it one more time to use the if statements instead of the try blocks.  The code runs fine but it is showing the regex as not matching.

Comment: Dangit.  You are right.  It is matching, I just haven't figured out where in my code I have it reporting incorrectly.

Comment: @SureThing, your test for whether it passed was incorrect. don't use m.start() > 0, because a successful match will have m.start() == 0. Also there's no reason to compile your regular expression in that code since you only use it once and compile it again every time you enter your function.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that checking the result of `match.start()` for being greater than `0` doesn't indicate the match was found, when it actually was.

```
>>> cregex1 = r'(HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\|HKCU\\|HKCU:\\)\\Software\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Office\\14\.0\\word\\security\\fileblock'
>>> m = re.search(cregex1, s, re.IGNORECASE)
>>> m.start()
0
>>> m.group(0)
'HKCU:\\\\Software\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Office\\14.0\\word\\security\\fileblock'
>>>
```

regex applied to

```
>>> print(s)
HKCU:\\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\14.0\word\security\fileblock\Word97Files = 5.
>>>
```

So in this snippet of code, the match succeeds, but `if findex > 0` isn't a good test for whether it did succeed or not because `match.start()` is going to be `0` when the match is found.

```
    findex = re.search(regex, content, re.IGNORECASE).start()
except:
    print('Registry path not found')
    findex = 0
if findex > 0:
    # An index matching the string was found
    regpathpass = True
```

This function could be rewritten like so:

```
# Elsewhere in code - maybe top of the file with other "constants".
REG_KEY_HKCU_OFF_FILEBLOCK = re.compile(<expr here>, re.IGNORECASE)
REG_KEY_WORD_FILES         = re.compile(<expr here>, re.IGNORECASE)

def stigeval(content, regex1, regex2):
    # Now set the registry key path and value (??)
    regpathpass = False
    regkeypass  = False
    try:
        regpathpass = regex1.search(content) != None
        if regpathpass:
            regkeypass = regex2.search(content) != None
    except re.error as err:
        print(f'Registry path not found due to error in expression: {err}')
        raise err  # You can do this if you want the error to go 
                   # up the call stack after you've printed the helpful
                   # message.

    return (regpathpass, regkeypass)
```

Assuming that the text being searched for by the regex expr's are worthy of being constants (frequent unvarying reuse), I put them already compiled at the top. They can be passed in as parameters when the func is called.

The function assumes already compiled regex's as params. If the keys passed to this function change a lot and it doesn't make sense to have constants for them. Then just use `re.search(<regex>...)` inside the func - and don't waste cycles compiling them since they're only used once.

As the other user who answered indicated, `try/except` blocks should encompass as much code as possible rather than single calls - *if possible*. I know that's not always the case. But in this instance, you could put a lot of code within the `try/except` and greatly simplify your function.

And another user commented that `except:` without capturing the specific exception is dangerous in this case because no matter what happened, the log output would be "path not found". A better strategy is to capture specifically bad expressions and include their message in output, or allow the error to get thrown up the call stack so the developer knows some other error type happened that they didn't predict could.

Comment: `except:` is evil, calling `stigeval(0, 0, 0)` will simply print "Registry path not found" and you'll never know what went wrong.

Comment: Thats a good point but the registry key should never be in the beginning of the content.  It will always have a hostname and timestamp before the registry key making the index not 0.  Right?

Comment: Additionally, I changed my except statements to match the re.error but when I do that, my code fails because the try block is coming back with a NONE attribute type and it has nothing else to fail to.  I think the root of my issue is this darn regex but by everything that I am seeing, the regex is written correctly.  I wish I could open a chat window with yall.

Comment: The regex was okay, but the test for it wasn't. Anyway, I don't understand your point @SureThing